# Is it possible to keep the old registration date for my domain that is shown in whois when moving my website to a new domain?

Tags: domains, domain-registration, whois, dates

I would like to transform my website from `www.namesite.example` to `www.namesite2.example`.  Is it possible to get the whois data to show the original data of the first domain registration? Or it is impossible?

So if for example `www.namesite.example` was registered in the year 2000, and in 2011 I've changed this domain to `www.namesite2.example`, can the  whois for `namesite2` show the year 2000 for registration?

Answer (score 3):

It is impossible.

The registries manage the data. What wou see through whois is just a read-only view of part of their database. So it is not specifically whois that is relevant here, but just the registries' data and their handling of it.

When a registry receive a domain registration order (typically from a registrar) it will then create a new record in its database and set the creation date to be the date the registration order has been received.

I think there exists one registry (but the case has left my memory) where you can change the name of a domain name, typically few days after creation to fix errors, in which case the initial date would be kept. But you are clearly not in this case, and even so it would have been specific to one TLD.